# Can we create any general HTML Component?

Tags: jquery, html, components, repeat

I have an HTML page. I have created a frame using background repeat function. It is like a dialog box as below :

[image]

The HTML Code for this is :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Frame
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="frame.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="frame.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frame">
    <div id="h" style="width:400px" class="h">Frame</div>
    <div id="l" style="height:400px" class="l"></div>
    <div id="r" class="r"></div>
    <div id="b" class="b"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var width = $('#h').width();
        var height = $('#l').height();
        var pad = $('#h').position().left;
        var actWidth = width + pad;
        var nHeight = height - (height * 2);
        var rLeftMargin = actWidth + 1;
        var bWidth = actWidth + 2;

        $('#r').css({'margin-top':nHeight});
        $('#h').css({'height':25});
        $('#r').css({'margin-left':rLeftMargin});
        $('#r').css({'height':height});
        $('#b').css({'width':bWidth});
        $('#b').css({'margin-top':0});
    }
)
```

And the CSS is :

```
.h{
background-image:url('images//line.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
padding-left:10px; 
color:white;
}
.l{
background-image:url('images//dot.jpg'); 
background-repeat: repeat-y; 
}
.r{
background-image:url('images//dot.jpg'); 
background-repeat: repeat-y; 
float:top;
}
.b{
background-image:url('images//dot.jpg'); 
background-repeat: repeat-x; 
height:1px;
}
```

Now, the problem is, this frame I can only use once. If I use is once again, then Ids get repeted & all the frame gets affected !!! This should not happen. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using IDs, use the classes you already have and just look over each frame independently, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".frame").each(function() {
     var width = $(this).find('.h').width(),
         height = $(this).find('.l').height(),
         pad = $(this).find('.h').position().left,
         actWidth = width + pad,
         nHeight = height - (height * 2),
         rLeftMargin = actWidth + 1,
         bWidth = actWidth + 2;

    $(this).find('.r').css({'margin-top':nHeight, 'margin-left':rLeftMargin, 'height':height});
    $(this).find('.h').css({'height':25});
    $(this).find('.b').css({'width':bWidth, 'margin-top':0});
  });
});
```

Just remove all IDs and change the wrapper to `<div class="frame">` to make this work.  By [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through each frame and using [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) like [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) you can get the elements with the matching classes inside the particular `<div>` you're currently on in the loop.

Comment: I have tried this. But, the problem coming is the right side of the frame is not being show !! It became an open frame !!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS to size div#frame, set the header image as a background positioned to the top and repeated and use css borders instead of background images? Change 'frame' as a class rather than an ID, and you can reuse as you wish.